# How to correct for non-linearity of response in linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity

I want to train a linear regression model to predict a non-linear variable. This how the two independent variables correlated against the response (points are jittered):

[image]

[image]

And the residuals against the fitted values:

[image]

Most of the values for the response are zero. The effect is a very strong heteroscedasticity

```
        studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  model
BP = 55483.84, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

event though the the predictors are strongly correlated with the response

```
Call:
lm(formula = response ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data = train_predictors)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.6996 -0.0268 -0.0238 -0.0182  4.8785 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.748e-02  2.825e-04   97.28   <2e-16 ***
predictor1   8.491e-05  6.574e-07  129.16   <2e-16 ***
predictor2  -3.934e-10  8.298e-12  -47.41   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1561 on 498498 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0365,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.0365 
F-statistic:  9442 on 2 and 498498 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Should I consider more adopting [non-linear models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61217/transforming-variables-for-multiple-regression-in-r) or could I first try correcting the non-linearity of the response?

Comment: "Linearity" (or lack thereof) refers to the relationship between the predictors and the response, about which you have offered no direct relevant information. Could you please amend your post to provide that?

Comment: In addition to @whuber's point, the marginal distribution of the response is not really of interest, but rather the conditional distribution / the distribution of the residuals. On another note, are all Y values integers / counts?

Comment: Some useful searches you can investigate include [multinomial logistic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multinomial+logistic+regression) and [ordinal regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ordinal+regression).

Comment: Is the response a *count* or does it represent some categorical thing, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know details of your model, but in my opinion you need to deal with the large amount of "zero responses". Look into compound models with a mass point at zero. Something like the "Tweedie model".