# How to apply transformations to the predictors of a GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, predictor

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116486/why-y-should-be-transformed-before-the-predictors) discusses why we need to transform $Y$ before estimating the predictors exponents in order to reduce the problem to a linear fit. The example builds on $Y$ log-normal. In the case of a GLM, we can run a BoxCox likelihood estimate on the predictors against $log(Y)$, then use a logit function in the GLM.

How can we estimate the predictor transformation when $Y$ is not log-normal, when using GLM? For example in the case of a Poisson $Y$ distribution with $X$ normal, how do we linearize $Y ~ X$?

Comment: How does a Pareto distribution imply nonlinearity of Y|X?

Comment: Well, at the tail of the distribution the, say, $X^3$ exponent will not fit the model as well as at the center of the $Y, X$ observations where $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X^3 + \epsilon$ is more stable.

Comment: Tail of the distribution of what?

Comment: Tails of $Y$ distribution. That is the reason we need to specify a family distribution and link function in GLM to indicate the kind $Y$ distribution, so that each predictor is "stretched" to fit $Y$.

Comment: How does the tail of the Y distribution imply nonlinearity of Y|X?

Comment: So if $Y$ is lognormal and $X$ is normal (like in the link I posted), it doesn't imply nonlinearity of $Y|X$. Only heteroskedasticity? I guess that makes sense...

Comment: So to go back to the original question, in this case we have Y Pareto and X normal. How do we transform the predictors? Don't we have to transform $Y$ before linearizing the predictors with a boxcox? In this case a $Y$ log transform won't make it....

Comment: You don't transform Y "because it's lognormal". The marginal distribution of $Y$ might be almost anything, without any issue at all. The assumptions relate to the conditional distribution of $Y$, (its distribution at each given value of $X$ -- and then primarily when you're trying to use that assumption in hypothesis testing or constructing intervals). This issue (that the distributional assumption applies to the conditional distribution of Y|X not the raw distribution of Y) is discussed in many posts.